# Why do medical emergency teams not beam?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-transporter

When there's a medical emergency on the Enterprise, is there a reason that the response teams don't beam directly to the injured? Would transporters not allow for quicker response and give patients a better chance of survival?

For example, in TNG S4E7 *Reunion*, when K'Ehleyr is dying, the medical team takes 1:30 to get to her quarters. Dr. Crusher later says that "there wasn't enough time to take her into stasis", which seems like a very good argument for transporters.

Comment: They do sometimes.

Comment: related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/172122/when-is-site-to-site-transport-perfected-in-star-trek

Comment: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Site-to-site_transport

Comment: Doctor Pulaski would have objected to being beamed to a patient

Comment: In DS9, Bashir often has himself and the patient beamed to sick bay, but does seem to travel by foot to the scene. In general, I think it depends on what the plot calls for.

Comment: Presumably, it's the same reason that (real-world) ambulance crews are trained to assess the situation for safety before entering a zone of potential danger. Beaming straight into an area where someone has been injured could easily put the medical teams into danger and result in more casualties being created.